# Is there a Chrome extension for having & remembering a different locale per tab?

Tags: windows, chrome, language

### Background

I write in both Hebrew and English. I switch between them using the default combination keys of ALT+SHIFT (I know it's different for other users around the world).

Windows OS has a function that allows to remember which locale to switch to per window, so if I switch between windows that I wrote in different languages, it auto switches to the language I wrote when I left it (though it's only this way if the process wasn't killed, sadly).

It looks like this:

[image]

### The problem

On Chrome (and its derivatives, and on all web browsers that I know of), the tabs are all on the same window.

This means that if I write in language X on one tab, and I switch to another tab that I previously wrote on language Y in, it stays on language X , so I have to switch again to language Y.

### What I've found

I actually haven't found any way to solve this. All of those workarounds didn't work:

1. Detaching the tab into a new window.
2. Creating a new window.
3. Opening a tab in incognito mode.

I tried asking this question on [**"superUser" webpage**](https://superuser.com/q/1395494/152400) , but they told me it's better to write here instead.

I've also requested to have this feature built into Chrome itself, [**here**](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/L8ExauRv6-s;context-place=forum/chrome), and I hope it's possible and that they will consider it.

### The question

Is there any solution for this? Something that will remember the language per tab, and maybe even one that will remember the language after restarting Chrome?

Maybe an extension? If this has to be only on the web browser side, is there maybe a forum that I can request this feature?